# CartThrob Is Calling It Quits... Can't Download Final Build 2.6.1

Tags: cartthrob

Edit (7.25.2015):
CartThrob has been acquired by Vector Media Group!  This question no longer really applies, but it will be left up for archival purposes.

---

So apparently and rather abruptly, CartThrob / MightyBigRobot is calling it quits and they are closing their business.  I do hope nothing catastrophic has happened and it is just a time for change for them.  I also wish them well on their future endeavors.  You can read their official statement at their website:

http://cartthrob.com/

Now, I have a CartThrob Pro license and after logging in to the site my purchases and downloads are not appearing.  I have not yet had a chance to download the most recent/final build of CartThrob, and as I transition to a new shopping cart solution I was hoping I would be able to get the most recent files for safekeeping.  If any CT support staff are still active and possibly reading this, is there any chance you could reactivate the purchases and downloads on the site for my account?

Are there any other CartThrob customers who are having the same issue not seeing their purchases and downloads on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still looking for help with this? I'm with Vector Media Group, and we've taken over CartThrob. More information can be found here: https://www.vectormediagroup.com/blog/view/vector-acquired-cartthrob-ct-admin/.

Can you [Submit a support request here](http://mightybigrobot.com/support/index.php?pg=request) with your information and we can look this up and get it resolved for you?

Comment: I just want to say, I'm ecstatic to see you guys coming in to pick up CartThrob!!! Thank you for your response and I'll go ahead and submit a support request right now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I appriciate your gander here, and I too hope it's not 'curtains' for BigMightyRobot, but rather bigger better things. However the nature of their leaving (no support, no contact, no refunds, but you can still buy it ) sounds like they are abandoning [insert your own reason why here]...

I assume that after the [link in the statement](http://cartthrob.com/site/) this is where your existing purchases are missing?

I would [contact BigMightyRobot direct](http://mightybigrobot.com/contact) and be firm. "I paid a premium price for your product, now your going out of business I require a copy of the goods I purchased". I mean if I purchased in April for development this month I'd be getting robbed, paid for products I can not recieve, thats not the right way to do business!

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that the link you posted is the one with the missing downloads.  Also, thanks for the link to the contact form, didn't see that one before.  I'll send them a note with that form -- I also contacted them via the developer's other site and will report back with any responses I receive.  They also previously had been somewhat active in support through Twitter, so I might try that as well.

Comment: Yea I saw the twitter feeds, seemed to die out a month or so ago. Also very strange that this shut down is soo out of the blue! Looking for news or details and nothings forth-coming. Suprising as they absorbed another add-on builder last year (GeoTagger makers) and they have ALOT of publisity over the web.